# I would like to click an image in a div that refreshes the page and hides the div after refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

EDIT 2

CONTEXT

I am using a semi-transparent image with a top-margin off-set to disable access to quiz content until the page is refreshed.

The code below works perfectly, on one page, one time:

JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { //document ready event
  //question element (to show/hide)
  const question1Elm = document.querySelector('#question-1');
  //localStorage element that gets the item with key question1Clicked
  const question1Clicked = window.localStorage.getItem('question1Clicked');
  //check if localStorage has item with key question1Clicked
  if (question1Clicked) { 
    //if found, hide element
    question1Elm.classList.add('quiz-lock-d-none');
  } else {
    // if not found, show element
    question1Elm.classList.add('quiz-lock');
    question1Elm.addEventListener('click', (event) => { //span click event
      // set localStorage item, key=question1Clicked, value=1
      window.localStorage.setItem('question1Clicked', '1')
      window.location.reload(); //reload
    });
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.quiz-lock img {
  margin-top: -235px;
}
.quiz-lock img:hover {
    margin-top: -235px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.quiz-lock-d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

HTML

```
[quiz shortcode]
<span id="question-1" class="quiz-lock">
<img src="images/lock-panel.png" />
</span>
```

There are 57 sections with a pre and post quiz on each. Multiple sections can be completed in a single sitting. The quiz lock needs to function on every section page individually.

When I incorporated the Set/Get for multiple elements detailed by naveen, the code looks like this:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { //document ready event
  //question element (to show/hide)
  const question1Elm = document.querySelector('#question-1');
  const clickedQuestions = JSOn.parse(localStorage.getItem('clickedQuestions')); //array
  //check if localStorage has item with key question1Clicked
  if (question1Clicked) { 
    //if found, hide element
    question1Elm.classList.add('quiz-lock-d-none');
  } else {
    // if not found, show element
    question1Elm.classList.add('quiz-lock');
    question1Elm.addEventListener('click', (event) => { //span click event
      window.localStorage.setItem('clickedQuestions', JSON.stringify([1, 3, 5))
      window.location.reload(); //reload
    });
  }
});
```

But breaks the functionality altogether.  I am obviously doing something wrong.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example You may also want to take the Tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour/

Comment: Show us what you got so far.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by **"drops to an anchor on the refreshed page where the image(div) use to be"**

Comment: I'm a newbie here and figuring things out. Thanks for your patience. I have edited my original post to clarify my issue. Thanks.

Comment: why do you want to refresh the page ?

Comment: We manage an LMS (Learning Management System) that includes both a pre and post quiz on each section page. We have found that for the post-quiz to function properly, the page needs to be refreshed after the pre-quiz has been taken. I am sure there are better ways to accomplish the desired outcome, but this is a quick stop-gap that should minimize support issues until a more permanent solution can be determined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To persist a value across reload you have to use either [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) / [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

#### Pseudo Code

HTML

```
<span id="question-1" class="quiz-lock">
    <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200x40/fff/aaa"/>
</span>
```

JavaScript

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => { //document ready event
  //question element (to show/hide)
  const question1Elm = document.querySelector('#question-1');
  //localStorage element that gets the item with key question1Clicked
  const question1Clicked = window.localStorage.getItem('question1Clicked');
  //check if localStorage has item with key question1Clicked
  if (question1Clicked) { 
    //if found, hide element
    question1Elm.classList.add('quiz-lock-d-none');
  } else {
    // if not found, show element
    question1Elm.classList.add('quiz-lock');
    question1Elm.addEventListener('click', (event) => { //span click event
      // set localStorage item, key=question1Clicked, value=1
      window.localStorage.setItem('question1Clicked', '1')
      window.location.reload(); //reload
    });
  }
});
```

CSS

```
.quiz-lock {
  margin-top: -235px;
}

.quiz-lock-d-none {
  display: none;
}
```

---

For multiple elements, use the logic in a loop and store the clicked question in an array in localStorage and set show/hide classes.

Set:

```
window.localStorage.setItem('clickedQuestions', JSON.stringify([1, 3, 5))
```

Get(if item exists):

```
const clickedQuestions = JSOn.parse(localStorage.getItem('clickedQuestions')); //array
```

P.S: Used `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` because `setItem` accepts only `DomString` as key and value

Comment: naveen - that amazingly appears to give me exactly what I needed, with one caveat. It appears to only work once. It would need to work for each section with the possibility of multiple sections being completed in a single sitting.  Outside of that, from what I saw the only time I was able to test it, it appeared to work perfectly.

Comment: I made the Set/Get edits to the JavaScript, as instructed(?) and broke the functionality altogether (see OP edits).  I am obviously doing something wrong.  Any additional help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: naveen - I'm unclear about your directions starting with "For multiple elements..." Will this allow the same functionality on other section pages during the same session?

Comment: you should loop through each and set values on page load whenther to show hide. should get the already clicked values from localStorage and them set those questions hidden